# Django REST Framework and related models with one field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to create a simple REST API for the following model:

I have a main entity called Product with some fields: name, price...
Also I have a related entity called Keyword with one single field: the keyword.

Each product can have one or more keywords.

I can easily translate this into two django models:

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Name of the product", max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField("Description of the product")
    price = models.IntegerField("Price of the product")
    received_at = models.DateField("Received at")

class Keyword(models.Model):
    keyword = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name="keywords")
```

But I'm lost with serializers.

I want a simple verb like this to create:

```
POST /products
{
  "name": "My product name",
  "description": "My product description",
  "price": 40,
  "received_at": "2015-12-1",
  "keywords": ["keyword1", "keyword2"]
}
```

And the common list all, list one, update and delete:

```
GET /products
[{"name": "Product 1"...}, {"name": "Product 2"...}]

GET /products/1
{"name": "Product 1", "description": ...}

PUT /products/1
{
  "name": "My product name",
  "description": "My product description",
  "price": 40,
  "received_at": "2015-12-1",
  "keywords": ["keyword2"]
}

DELETE /products/1
```

The problem is manage the keywords.
When a new product is created all keywords are created
When a product is updated I have to check which keywords are news and which keywords have been deleted.

Also I want my API can be extensible in the near future with more relations like the "Keyword relation" with a simple string field.

Any ideas?

Comment: Since you want to post keywords along with the products, you'll have to write the logic manually. DRF right now doesn't support POST request of nested relation, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing the underlying keywords as members of a [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset). Then you can simply call the `add` method with each new keyword and the set will keep it a unique grouping, by the nature of how sets work.

```
a = set()
a.add('keyword1')
a.add('keyword2')
a.add('keyword1')
print(a)
```

Output:

```
set(['keyword1', 'keyword2'])
```

Comment: Yes, a set is a good option. However, an update request can contains less keywords than the stored keywords. I can do set(validated_data.get('keywords')) - set(instance.keywords) to get the new keywords and set(instance.keywords) - set(validated_data.get('keywords')) to get the removed keywords. Is there a cleaner solution to do this?